# 'NSSecureCoding!' is not a subtype of 'NSURL' using Swift when trying to replace closure argument type

Tags: share, swift, nsurl, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm using the 
`loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler:` method on an NSItemProvider object to extract a url from Safari via a Share extension in iOS 8.

In Objective-C, this code compiles and works:

```
    [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(@"public.url" options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
        //My code
    }];
```

In Swift however, I'm getting "NSSecureCoding!' is not a subtype of 'NSURL" compile error when I try to do something similar:

```
    itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (urlItem:NSURL, error:NSError!) in
        //My code
    })
```

If I add the bang to NSURL argument type as in `NSURL!` I get "Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'Void'" compile error. And if I leave the default argument typed as `NSSecureCoding!`, it compiles, but the block/closure doesn't run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify the types for urlItem or error as they can be inferred from the declaration of loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler. Just do the following:

```
itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { 
    (urlItem, error) in
    //My code
})
```

Even better, you can move the closure outside of the method call:

```
itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil) {
    (urlItem, error) in
    //My code
}
```

Comment: This compiles, however the closure doesn't execute.

Comment: That block is: "A block to be called when an item provider loads an item from an extension object’s attachments property." I would assume that there are no attachments.

Comment: `itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url")` returns `YES` so I'm assuming there must be a valid attachment.

Comment: hmm ya. I haven't played around with extensions yet so I'm not sure what is going on, but the closure syntax is correct. It isn't being called for a different reason. Maybe another question is in order for that.

Comment: I had a similar problem earlier in Obj-C, and my Info.plist file was the culprit and fixed that. I'm using the exact same plist setup here with Swift now, so I'm at a loss to what the issue might be.

Comment: You can verify the attachment type exists via `hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier`. I am trying the same but for `kUTTypeImage`. It's confirmed the image is in the attachment yet `if let image = item as? UIImage {} else {}` results in the `else` being called, the item casts to `nil` for `UIImage`. The exact same approach works fine in Objective-C. :[

Answer (score 2):

This API makes use of reflection internally: it looks at the type of the block’s first parameter to decide what to return. This is dependent on Objective-C’s looser enforcement of the block signature compared to Swift — and therefore does not work in Swift. (Yes, still.) See this [discussion on the developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24368).

I recommend [filing a bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) and writing small Objective-C wrapper methods to read each type of data you need.

It’s possible I’ve overlooked something. If someone has found a neat way to make this work in Swift I’m keen to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

The new API to use is canLoadObject and loadObject, use it as this:

```
if (itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self)) {
            print("==== attachment is URL")
            itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self, completionHandler:       
            {
                (data, error) in
                print("==== url object = \(data)")
            })
}
```

The same can be used for UIImage

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/data_delivery_with_drag_and_drop

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you or other ones still need a solution, it is simple. Just add a side variable with a cast to NSURL. Here it is:

```
itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil) {
(urlItem, error) in
    let url : NSURL = urlItem : NSURL
    // Whatever you like to do with your new url
}
```